# Scientific notation and usage thereof

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conventions, units, notation, error-analysis

I'm taking my first physics exam in university this Saturday, and I'm currently working on a practice exam.

I got the answer 3.1MeV for a alpha-decay question, but the answer was 3100keV. I understand that they represent the same thing, but why is my way of answering discouraged? Are there actual reasons? Might I lose points on my exam for answering like I did here?

EDIT: 0.31MeV is **not** equal to 3100keV...

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question.

Comment: "I understand that they represent the same thing," No, they are a factor of 10 different. You would certainly lose marks for making *that* mistake!

Comment: Then what the question is now?

Comment: Fundamentally we can't answer questions about why your paper was marked as it was. In the absence of explicit instructions to answer in $\mathrm{keV}$ I would have accepted $3.1\,\mathrm{MeV}$.

Answer (score 1):

Within reason if they are both correct values either answer should be acceptable.
The idea of using prefixes is to avoid the use of very small or very large numerical values.
For example it is probably best not to quote a value as 3,100,000 eV or 0.0000031 TeV.

Answer (score 1):

In 3100 keV the number of significant figures is ambiguous; you could be claiming 2, 3 or 4. But 3.1 MeV is unambiguous: 2 sig figs! If you were claiming 4 sig figs, you'd write 3.100 MeV. That's why I prefer the larger unit!

Comment: Someone didn't like this answer. It would be good if they explained the reason for their dislike; we might learn something!

Comment: My experience is that you will not get a reply. I have noticed that sometimes all answers are downvoted for no obvious (to me) reason. Personally I do not often down vote but when I do I like to give a reason.

Comment: You're right! Even an agreed code (e.g. B = contains bad Physics, A = doesn't answer question, H = unnecessarily hard to follow, Q = question shouldn't be answered) would be better than nothing.

Comment: @PhilipWood I didn't downvote, but "significant figures" are not a very serious method of showing accuracy, except in school work. "Using a large unit" doesn't help if you want to express things like $3100 \pm 60$ keV or $3100$ keV $\pm 10$%.

Comment: I agree that sig figs are a wholly inadequate way of showing uncertainty, but surely they have a place as a useful informal guide.